# Return the text of each span using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im able to get the list of all spans having the attribute dir='somevalue', with the following jquery statement

```
$("span[dir='somevalue']")
```

I want the text of each span i.e. for example, `<span dir='somevalue'> text </span>`, i need the value 'text', and i want this for every span returned by the previous statement.
Any way to do this using Jquery ?

Thank You

Answer (score 7):

I think is a good case to use [Traversing/map](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/map):

```
var values = $("span[dir='somevalue']").map(function(){
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

The `values` variable is now an `Array` that contains on each array element the inner text of each `span` matched by your selector.

If you want to concatenate all the values in a string, you can use [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Join):

```
var allValues = values.join(" "); // using a space as separator between values
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("span[dir='somevalue']").text()
```

will give you the concatenation of all the text. If you want an array and are using Javascript 1.8 you can use

```
$("span[dir='somevalue']")
    .get()
        .reduce(function (a,b) { return a.concat([$(b).text()]); }, [])
```

Comment: CMS's version is much nicer than mine!

Answer (score 0):

or

```
var values = [];
$("span[dir='somevalue']").each(function(){
    values.push($this.text());
});
```

a bit boring but easy to understand.